Turn click event on and off
I feel lke there must be a more streamlined way to do this than re-executing the whole click event code each time.
In 'big' mode, I don't need the overlay, so I shut it off. But I want it to work when I switch back to 'default' or 'smol' mode.
My sizer buttons:
<a href="javascript:false" class="smol" onclick="sizer('smol')">Small</a>
<a href="javascript:false" class="default" onclick="sizer('default')">Default</a>
<a href="javascript:false" class="big" onclick="sizer('big')">Big</a>

// my generated content
<article>My content 1</article>
<article>My content 2</article>
// etc.
<div id="overlay" onclick="hideOverlay()"></div>

My sizer function:
function sizer(sz) {
    // a bunch of CSS to resize my content

    if (sz=="big") { 
        enableOverlay(false);
    }
    else {
        enableOverlay(true);
    }
}

Turning the overlay click functionality on and off (ctually, destroying it and recreating it each time)
function enableOverlay(state){
    if (state) { // sizer is 'default' or 'smol'
        // set article to show overlay when clicked
        $( "article" ).on("click", function(){
            // build the contents of the overlay on-the-fly for this article
            var aside = $(this).find("aside");
            var o = $("#overlay");
            o.contents().remove(); //destroy old content
            o.append(aside[0].innerHTML); // add new content
            o.css("display","block");
        });
    }
    else { // sizer is 'big'
        // disable article click event
        $( "article" ).off();
    }
}

function hideOverlay(){
    // hide when clicked
    $("#overlay").hide()
}

And of course, I start off in default mode:
$( document ).ready(function() {
    enableOverlay(true);
});

Isn't there a way of keeping the click event bound but disabling it temporarily?

Maybe I will try to add a temporary variable.
let overlayEnabled = true;

function sizer(sz) {
    // a bunch of CSS to resize my content

    overlayEnabled = sz !== 'big';
}

$( "article" ).on("click", function(){
    if (!overlayEnabled) {
        return;
    }
    // build the contents of the overlay on-the-fly for this article
    var aside = $(this).find("aside");
    var o = $("#overlay");
    o.contents().remove(); //destroy old content
    o.append(aside[0].innerHTML); // add new content
    o.css("display","block");
});


or if you don't want a flag variable, you can set data attribute on the overlay.
function sizer(sz) {
    // a bunch of CSS to resize my content

    $("#overlay").attr('data-enabled', sz !== 'big')
}

$( "article" ).on("click", function(){
    const enabled = $("#overlay").attr('data-enabled');

    // notice: the type of enabled is string
    if (enabled === 'false') {
        return;
    }
    // rest of code
})

